# Create a program that sums the diagonal of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, controls, structure, diagonal

I'm trying to create a program that sums the diagonal of a matrix that I've created. I used the code below but I don't understand whats wrong with the code I made.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3) 
b <- c(3, 5, 6)

x <- matrix(a, b, nrow=3, ncol=3)
x

for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(x)) {
    if (i=j) {
      diags[i, j] <- sum(x[i, j])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using `=` (value assignment) instead of `==` (comparison), so `i` becomes `j` and can't be found, but even so `diags` would be the next undefined thing to throw an error, and after that `sum(diags[i, j])` would return each individual diagonal's element's sum instead of the sum along the diagonal. You can obtain the desired result with `sum(diag(x))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already great code! However, as was noted in comments, you were trying to `sum` a scalar when you probably thought you were summing a vector. You need to add the result of `x[i, j]` to a starting value which is of course zero. So first create `diags` with value zero and add the result to it in each iteration of the loop.

*Notes:* for comparisons we use `` `==` ``, for assignment in function calls `=`, and for assignment in the script `` `<-` ``. Better use the `seq` functions such as `seq_len(nrow(x))` instead of `1:nrow(x)`; yields at first glance the same, but has advantages e.g. if `nrow(x)` is zero.

```
diags <- 0

for (i in seq_len(nrow(x))) {
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(x))) {
    if (i == j) {
      diags <- diags + x[i, j]
    }
  }
}
diags
# [1] 9
```

Checking with the `diag` function.

```
sum(diag(x))
# [1] 9
```

---

*Data:*

I used a slightly different matrix, that isn't so symmetric and has more distinguishable values.

```
x <- matrix(1:9 , nrow=4, ncol=3)
```